# Contract ended during probation on EU blue card

Tags: immigration, blue-card, employment, visa-change, unemployment-benefits

Just 5 days before my probation (6 months) ended, I was informed by email from my boss (a university professor) that he will terminate my contract by the end of September (7 months in total).
Yesterday, I got a letter stating the same and also saying "since we are informing you a month in advance, you need to inform the employment agency within 3 days.
Today I went there and they initially said that they can't do anything since I have only worked for 6 months in Germany but later on, when I told them I have worked in France for past 4 years, they let me into the job center.
At the job center, I was told that I need to go to the immigration office to get a new card because my blue card is tied to this previous job and employer. I have some questions:

1. Does that mean I need to get permission from the Abh to change employer? Should I do that even before I have been offered a new job?
2. Would the ABH give me a new 3 month job seeking visa and take away my blue card valid until March 2023?
3. How urgent is it to inform ABH about my unemployment status? I would like to stay longer than 3 months to find a job.
4. Do I have to involved employment agency at all? Can I just keep my card and keep looking for jobs and once I get one, I inform ABH?